How do you mock a webservice callout to the Apex MDAPI Wrapper?
I wrote some code that calls the Apex Wrapper for the Metadata API (apex-mdapi)
// establish service
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.endpoint_x = 'callout:ApexMDApi' + '/services/Soap/m/42.0';
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = '{!$Credential.OAuthToken}';

// use service to fetch org's default SecuritySettings
MetadataService.SecuritySettings orgSecuritySettings =
        (MetadataService.SecuritySettings)
            service.readMetadata('SecuritySettings',new List<String>{'Security'}).getRecords()[0];
    

I looked at the examples in the repo's MetadataServiceTest class to see how to mock the WebService callout in my test methods.  These examples weren't very illuminating because they were just there for code coverage.
private class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock 
{
    public void doInvoke(
        Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
        String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
        String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType) 
    {
        if(request instanceof MetadataService.retrieve_element)
            response.put('response_x', new MetadataService.retrieveResponse_element());
        else if(request instanceof MetadataService.checkDeployStatus_element)
            response.put('response_x', new MetadataService.checkDeployStatusResponse_element());
        ...
} 

Since my code-under-test does something with the retrieved SecuritySettings, I need to mock something other than an empty object as shown in the examples.
How do I do this?

It is easy to be overwhelmed with all the inner classes defined in the apex-mdapi MetadataService.cls

In my example, I was dealing with Metadata type SecuritySettings
Look for these two inner classes within MetadataService.cls:

ReadSecuritySettingsResult
readSecuritySettinsgResponse_element


If your code was retrieving some other Metadata type such as ProfilePasswordPolicy, you would look for inner classes:

ReadProfilePasswordPolicyResult
readProfilePasswordPolicyResponse_element


If your code was using a different MDAPI verb like listMetadata then there might be only one inner class as in:

listMetadataResponse_element



But basically, you are looking for the appropriate inner class that ends in ..._element.
Carrying on with my SecuritySettings read example
ReadSecuritySettingsResult (inner class)
public class ReadSecuritySettingsResult implements IReadResult {
    public MetadataService.SecuritySettings[] records;
    public MetadataService.Metadata[] getRecords() { return records; }
    private String[] records_type_info = new String[]{'records',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','-1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{SOAP_M_URI,'true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'records'};
}

readSecuritySettingsResponse_element (inner class)
public class readSecuritySettingsResponse_element implements IReadResponseElement {
    public MetadataService.ReadSecuritySettingsResult result;
    public IReadResult getResult() { return result; }
    private String[] result_type_info = new String[]{'result',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{SOAP_M_URI,'true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'result'};
}

and my WebserviceMock class used in my test method
public class MockMDApiWebServiceCallout implements WebServiceMock {
    
    public void doInvoke(
        Object stub,
        Object request,
        Map<String, Object> response,  // <== the important one
        String endpoint,
        String soapAction,
        String requestName,
        String responseNS,
        String responseName,
        String responseType) {

        response.put('response_x', mockOrgSecuritySettings()); // should be an object of the xxx_element type
            
    }

with helper class that constructs the mock webservice response in detail
private MetadataService.readSecuritySettingsResponse_element mockOrgSecuritySettings() {
    MetadataService.readSecuritySettingsResponse_element mockReadResult = 
        new MetadataService.readSecuritySettingsResponse_element();


        // Build up the apexType for SecuritySettings.PasswordPolicies
        MetadataService.SecuritySettings mockSecuritySettings = new MetadataService.SecuritySettings();
        MetadataService.PasswordPolicies mockPasswordPolicies = new MetadataService.PasswordPolicies();
        mockPasswordPolicies.expiration = 'ThirtyDays'; // <== the mock value
        ... other values to mock as needed
        mockSecuritySettings.passwordPolicies = mockPasswordPolicies;

        //  Stuff into the ApexType that implements MetadataService.IReadResult
        mockReadResult.result = new MetadataService.ReadSecuritySettingsResult();
        mockReadResult.result.records = new List<MetadataService.SecuritySettings>{mockSecuritySettings};
        return mockReadResult;
    }

Notes

Unlike mocking REST calls where you typically would return JSON, for the apex MDAPI, you mock ApexTypes within MetaDataService. You (fortunately) don't have to mock any XML at all such as would be returned from a true SOAP call to the MDAPI.

